# Windows authentication with asp.net

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, windows-authentication

I am building a website using ASP.net and C#. For users to get on my website they need to authenticate themselves with windows authentication.

I am now trying to store the name where the user authenticates itself with in a session so i can use it later on in my website.

Does anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Session["UserName"] = value;
```

Then you can retreive it like that:

```
string username = (string)Session["UserName"];
```

OR

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var someSession = '<%= Session["UserName"].ToString() %>';
</script>
```

Comment: Then i give the username myself but i want to get the same name as the name they use to login.

Comment: I hope the article in this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12614/How-to-Get-Window-NT-Logged-User-Name-Using-ASP-NE) will help you  @Urjen

Comment: U are a hero, that was EXACTLY where i was searching for. My google skills failed me again apperently.

Comment: @Urjen Glad to help you. Please mark as answer if that solved your problem. Thanks.